# Is that possible to hide request URL using Servlet/RequestDispatcher?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I'm working in a JSF 2 project that has "something" that hide the URL during navigation. I said "something" because I couldn't figure it out yet...I believe something related of JSF or Primefaces but I can't get what exactly.

I was asked to perform a solution that will become possible to do login on the web project by the desktop project.

I am just making some tests about it but what I did was a Servlet as I can't call the ManagedBean from the desktop application, so that I open the browser passing something some parameter then the Servlet create the session.

The primary problem I noticed is that when the login is performed in this way browser starts to show the url navigation and it is a undesirable behaviour. I think it has something related to the URL I called from the desktop application and the RequestDispatcher.

this is the URL showed when login is made by login.xhtml -> http://localhost:9080/myContextRoot/

and this is what happens when login is made by Servlet -> http://localhost:9080/myContextRoot/pages/business/index.xhtml

Could I get any tips???

Here is how I open the browser

```
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
```

And the Servlet

```
 @WebServlet(name = "servletLogin", urlPatterns = "/ServletLogin")
public class LogonServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
 if (validated()) {
 req.setAttribute("user", user);
        req.getRequestURL();
        req.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/business/index.xhtml");   
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
        return;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide" the URL?  In the user's browser address bar?

Comment: I'd like to show it as the first example http://localhost:9080/myContextRoot/ note that there is no folder, page name, extension, parameter. It is the default behaviour when the login is done by login.xhtml but when It is done by the servlet it ends up showing the whole navigation url after myContextRoot